# HTTP Connection Posting data twice

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish

I am writing an application in which I am using Http Connection to post data on a server. My App is working fine when I check it in emulator. My Webservice take too much time to generating responses and my emulator is also responding in a proper way. Somehow when I installed the app on the device, my app is posting data twice on the server. I have checked it... Does anyone have any solution on how to escape from this???

Here I am attaching my code of the sending request. I think the mobile app is sending another request when it reaches HTTP Time out, but I don't know what's the problem. Please Help me.

```
String param=
   "function=OpenRecharge&LoginId="+SharedVariable.getUserInfo().getLoginID()
              +"&BatchId="+SharedVariable.getSelectedProduct().getBatchID()
              +"&SystemServiceID="+SharedVariable.getSelectedProduct().getSystemServiceID()
              +"&ReferalNumber="+strMobileNo
              +"&Amount="+strAmount
              +"&FromANI="+fromMoNo
              +"&Email="
              +"&Checksum="+Checksum;
System.out.println("Final Parameter:\n"+param);

connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);

//Connector.open(param, strAmount, quit)
connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-1.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept_Language","en-US");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

OutputStream out = connection.openOutputStream();
out.write(param.getBytes());

out.flush();
//System.out.println("Status Line Code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
//System.out.println("Status Line Message: " + connection.getResponseMessage());

is=connection.openDataInputStream();
int chr;
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
while ((chr = is.read()) != -1)
    sb.append((char) chr);

System.out.println("Response===>"+sb.toString());
```

Comment: I strongly suspect it is because you have same code in both onCreate and onResume.

Comment: Without a fuller code quote I'd agree with thinksteep's comment as possible cause

Comment: @thinksteep: buddy..this is j2me code..not an android code,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you serve up an answer with a place holder text like, "processing..." then after a delay have the web browser try again?

Answer (score 1):

I´m not app developer, anyway your web sevice shouldn´t have a big delay for response. I think this is your problem and you should resolve it. Making a cache or pre-process your response.

Although you can change timeout (it seems fixed), it´s not recommendable beacuse many mobile (wap) proxies have timeout of 30s.